# Send e-mail based on SharePoint list status

Tags: workflow, email

I'm a newbie with SharePoint at the moment and I'd like to get a status update when someone changes a status in my list.
I currently have an extensive status list and have set up a calculated helper column to change its' content to either "Yes" or "No" when a status is changed to one that requires more information from me.

The following workflow is set up referencing that helper column but after countless changes I get no e-mail.
It worked at some point in the beginning for this item when I didn't use the helper column but I can't even replicate that any more.
[image: SharePoint]

I'm lost, can anyone possibly help me?

Comment: Make sure you not testing with System account ( sometime as Administrator). Try to use a different account for initial test.

Comment: Do you mean testing by changing the status of the items myself or? Because as I mentioned earlier it already worked once when I did the changes myself but now not any more.

Comment: Try to update item that makes workflow to send email, do this with some other user account.

Comment: I changed the e-mail address but no improvement...

Comment: I was asking to log in as different user in your SharePoint environment and do needful to make Workflow run and send email. I am trying to make sure item is not updated as System account due to which an Event does not fires.

Answer (score 0):

You need an email when user changed the status in List.
So try to create a new workflow "Send email to user".Then add your workflow to your list  and change the execution steps like When the Item is changed.

result Whenever the item has been change d you will get a notification email.So no need to put extra steps in your workflow. If the problem exists share the error details.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was that the workflow was set to only activate on change of item, as soon as I also ticked the activate on creation the workflow worked.